# Проверочное слово для слова "орфография"

Tags: проверочные-слова

Какое проверочное слово для слова **орфография**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Орфография* — это заимствованное слово, пришедшее в русский язык из греческого. Элементы слова образуют смысловое единство: *орфо* — правильно, *граф* — пишу. Литературно это слово можно перевести как *правописание*. Проверить, соответственно, никак нельзя, только этимологическим способом.

Comment: Спасибо ооогромное !!!